# How to display xml dile data in datagridview in winform

Tags: c#, xml, gridview

I have xml file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CONSOLIDATED_LIST dateGenerated="2015-01-23T00:00:00">
  <INDIVIDUALS>
    <INDIVIDUAL> 
      <DataId>1</DataId> 
      <Name>Hitesh</Name> 
      <Address>Mumbai</Address> 
    </INDIVIDUAL>
    <INDIVIDUAL> 
      <DataId>2</DataId> 
      <Name>Jitesh</Name> 
      <Address>Mumbai</Address> 
    </INDIVIDUAL>
    <INDIVIDUAL> 
      <DataId>3</DataId> 
      <Name>Ritesh</Name> 
      <Address>Mumbai</Address> 
    </INDIVIDUAL>
    <INDIVIDUAL> 
      <DataId>4</DataId> 
      <Name>Mitesh</Name> 
      <Address>Mumbai</Address> 
    </INDIVIDUAL>
    <INDIVIDUAL> 
      <DataId>5</DataId> 
      <Name>Nitesh</Name> 
      <Address>Mumbai</Address> 
    </INDIVIDUAL> 
  </INDIVIDUALS
  <ENTITY>
    <ENTITIES> 
      <DataId>11</DataId>
      <Name>Hitesh</Name> 
      <Address>Mumbai</Address> 
    </ENTITIES>
    <ENTITIES> 
      <DataId>12</DataId> 
      <Name>Hitesh</Name> 
      <Address>Mumbai</Address> 
    </ENTITIES>
    <ENTITIES> 
      <DataId>13</DataId> 
      <Name>Hitesh</Name>
      <Address>Mumbai</Address> 
     </ENTITIES> 
   </ENTITY> 
 </CONSOLIDATED_LIST>
```

My code is

```
openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
txtXML.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
txtXML.Font = new Font(txtXML.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(openFileDialog1.FileName);


**dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];**  ------Error (Only shows First table i.e. <CONSOLIDATED_LIST dateGenerated="2015-01-23T00:00:00">)
ds.Dispose();
```

And when i put this

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[2];
```

it displays only INDIVIDUAL tag data , not ENTITY data.

Comment: @Nikolay Kostov : use http://xmltoolbox.appspot.com/ to format XML please

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why the "-" characters in from of some opening tags in your XML sample ? Is this really part of your XML data, or is it just some artifact from your text editor ?